# How does use the Bulk Resave Elements command with checkbox group fields?

Tags: console, resave, checkbox

I recently added a Checkbox Group with 3 options to a Section. By default, I would want the checkboxes to be checked, and to allow the author to uncheck them as needed.

To apply the above "checked by default" state to the hundreds of already-existing entries in the section, I thought I'd be able to use the [Bulk Resaving Entries](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/bulk-resaving-elements) command line ability, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with `MultiOptionsFieldData`. The examples provided only cover adjusting the data in a plain text field.

I've tried various permutations on `php craft resave/entries --section mySection --set checkboxGroupField[0] --to "=1"`, with no luck. Any pointers? Thanks!